# JPA Composite Key that references another Composite Key

Tags: hibernate, kotlin, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I have three tables, two of which have a composite Primary Key, and one of those composite keys references the other:

```
VEHICLE
| MAKE | MODEL | NOTES |
Primary Key = Make + Model

VEHICLE_LABEL
| VEH_MAKE | VEH_MODEL | LAB_ID | ORDER |
Primary Key = VEH_MAKE + VEH_MODEL + LAB_ID

LABEL
| ID | NAME | NOTES |
Primary Key = ID
```

Because of the extra columns on the join table I have created `VehicleLabel` as its own `Entity`

Vehicle:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE")
class Vehicle @PersistenceConstructor constructor(
    @EmbeddedId
    val key: ID,

    @Column(name = "NOTES")
    val notes: String
) {
    @Embeddable
    class ID(
        @Column(name = "MAKE")
        val make: String,

        @Column(name = "MODEL")
        val model: String
    ) : Serializable
}
```

Vehicle Label:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "VEHICLE_LABEL")
class VehicleLabel @PersistenceConstructor constructor(
    @EmbeddedId
    val key: ID,

    @Column(name = "ORDER")
    val order: Int
) {
    @Embeddable
    class ID @PersistenceConstructor constructor(
        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumns(
            JoinColumn(name = "VEH_MAKE", referencedColumnName = "MAKE"),
            JoinColumn(name = "VEH_MODEL", referencedColumnName = "MODEL")
        )
        val vehicle: Vehicle,

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "LAB_ID")
        val label: Label
    ) : Serializable
}
```

Label:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "LABEL")
class Label(
    @Id
    @Column(name = "ID")
    val id: String,

    @Column(name = "NAME")
    val name: String

    @Column(name = "NOTES")
    val notes: String
)
```

When I run the above though I get

```
InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: Provided id of the wrong type for class repository.Vehicle. Expected: class repository.Vehicle$ID, got class java.lang.String
```

I've tried swapping the `VehicleLabel.ID` so that instead of containing the full `Vehicle` it contains the `Vehicle.ID` but I get the same error. Ideally I'd prefer not to do this though.

Note: I am trying to avoid adding an ID to the `VEHICLE` table as uniqueness is already ensured via the `MAKE` + `MODEL`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the error was from a Test Class that was calling `entityManager.find(Vehicle::class, "model")`.

It was legacy from when the Vehicle ID was just the `model` field.